# Error al selecionar huella de bases de datos

Tags: mysql, c#

Ando haciendo un reloj checador con un lector de huella, ya logre hacer que inserte a la base de datos, pero en la seccion de verificar la huella me marca error, tengo este codigo en esa parte, estoy usando c# y lo que esta comentado lo agarre usando entities, pero lo quiero en mysql.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Edita tu pregunta y pon el código como texto

Comment: Te respondieron con texto, por favor procura no poner a los demás a replicar tu problema desde una imagen. No es mucho más complicado copiar y pegar a tomar la captura y sí nos permite ayudarte más fácil

Answer (score 0):

Hola en el reader antes de obtener los datos debes de poner

```
if(r.Read()) { /*tu código para leer*/};
```

Ejemplo

```
 using (SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
 {
   if (reader.Read())
     {
         var dato = reader["Mi dato"]               
     }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Ya lo solucione amigos,

use este codigo

```
private void UpdateStatus(int FAR)
    {
        // Show "False accept rate" value
        SetStatus(String.Format("False Accept Rate (FAR) = {0}", FAR));
    }

    protected override void Process(DPFP.Sample Sample)
    {
        base.Process(Sample);

        // Process the sample and create a feature set for the enrollment purpose.
        DPFP.FeatureSet features = ExtractFeatures(Sample, DPFP.Processing.DataPurpose.Verification);

        // Check quality of the sample and start verification if it's good
        // TODO: move to a separate task
        DPFP.Verification.Verification.Result result = new DPFP.Verification.Verification.Result();

        DPFP.Template template = new DPFP.Template();
        Stream stream;

        try { 
        conexion.Open();

        String sql = "select * from empleado";
        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(sql, conexion);
        MySqlDataReader r = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        while (r.Read() )
        {

            stream = new MemoryStream((byte[])r["huella"]);
            template = new DPFP.Template(stream);
            Verificator.Verify(features, template, ref result);
            UpdateStatus(result.FARAchieved);

            if (result.Verified)
            {
                var nom = r["nombre"].ToString();
                MakeReport("The fingerprint was VERIFIED. " + nom);
            }
               
        }
            conexion.Close();
        }
        catch(Exception exe)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(exe.ToString());
        }
    }
```